# npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory

Tags: jenkins, npm

This error suddenly showed up when we run build on our Jenkins server. We did not change anything.

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v10.15.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/node_modules/.staging/@types/datatables.net-2acd857c/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! errno -20
npm ERR! syscall open
```

Answer (score 3):

We had the same error suddenly in the Jenkins build. We found out it was caused when running `npm i` on a specific module.

In our case it was caused because of an update that was made to a dependency package (`@types/mime`) in one the used packages (`@types/serve-static`).

Because the project is a legacy one, we could not update any packages, so to solve the issue we had to prevent the main package (`@types/serve-static)` from getting the latest version of the dependency (`"@types/mime" "*"`).

The way to do that was by declaring the specific version package in `package.json` file instead of letting the package install the dependency itself

```
    "@types/mime": "2.0.3"
```